# jQuery function Need to click twice to run but want first div to be visible

Tags: html, jquery, css

I created a dropdown menu in which you can select three divs to show. I want the first div to show on page load and when selecting a option from dropdown the div changes to the one selected.
All divs are in same location so they replace each other on click. This is working but because the first div is not set on "display: none" the script fires first to hide it. I don't know how to skip the first hiding but to switch right away to the other div.

Other than that I would like the function to only switch between divs and not hide it completely so that there's always content showing.

Thanks in advance!

I'm using this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.toggle').on('click', function(){
    var targetBox = $(this).attr('target-box'); // Find the target box

    $('.box').not(targetBox).hide(500); // Hide all other boxes
    
    $(targetBox).toggle(500); // Toggle the current state of this one
  });
});</script>
```

And this HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown">      
        <li class="-selector">
            <a>Choose &#9662;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-lb">
                <li><a class="toggle" target-box="#box1">Selector 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="toggle" target-box="#box2">Selector 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="toggle" target-box="#box3">Selector 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>


<div class="box1 box">CONTENT HERE<div>
<div class="box2 box" style="display:"none">CONTENT HERE<div>
<div class="box3 box" style="display:"none">CONTENT HERE<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some problems in your html.

You are using `#` in the `target-box` (`target-box="#box3"`) but the content you want to show us having classes and not `id`.

Also look at this line `<div class="box2 box" style="display:"none">CONTENT HERE<div>` 
 You haven't closed the div correct and your have a `"` inside your `style`

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    var targetBox = $(this).attr('target-box'); // Find the target box

    $('.box').not(targetBox).hide(500); // Hide all other boxes

    $(targetBox).show(500); // Toggle the current state of this one
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="-selector">
    <a>Choose &#9662;</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-lb">
      <li><a class="toggle" target-box=".box1">Selector 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="toggle" target-box=".box2">Selector 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="toggle" target-box=".box3">Selector 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="box1 box">CONTENT HERE
</div>
<div class="box2 box" style="display: none ">CONTENT HERE
</div>
<div class="box3 box " style="display: none">CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you maybe have a solution for the divs to not hide but only switch so there's alway content showing. So for example clicking selector 2 twice doesn't hide box 2?